# Probability theory problem - the order of drawing tickets doesn't matter

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

I found this problem in a textbook. It is given right after the theory about the Bayes' rule and the total probability rule.

---

**Problem:** We have an urn with $N$ lottery tickets of which $M \le N $are winning tickets.
$K$ persons $K \le N$ take turns drawing tickets from the urn in order.
Each person draws one ticket.

Prove that each person (no matter of his order number)
has a probability of $M/N$ for drawing a winning ticket.

---

- I can prove this statement for persons $1$ and $2$ using the total probability law, but I cannot quite formalize the proof for the $K$-th person. I have the feeling that the total probability law has to be used here.
- I have this approach in mind which I am not sure if it's rigorous enough. Here it is:

Obviously the probability of each ticket being a winning ticket is $M/N$.
Let's suppose it's person #$K$'s turn to draw and he draws some ticket $A$.

Now we define these events:

$H_1$: ticket A is a winning ticket
$H_2$: ticket A is not a winning ticket
$B$: person #$K$ has drawn a winning ticket

Using the total probability law we get:
$P(B) = P(H_1) P(B|H_1) + P(H_2) P(B|H_2) = ( M/N ) \cdot 1 + ((N-M)/N) \cdot 0 = M/N$

But this solution is weird to me because I feel like
I am already assuming what I need to prove.
I don't know if this approach is valid, is it?

If it's not, how can this problem be solved more rigorously?

- And finally, I was also thinking of another approach: some sort of induction by K.
  But it didn't lead me anywhere (at least for now).

So... is the above approach valid and if not, what is the best way to solve this problem rigorously *(without using any complex apparatus of course, because this problem is in the very beginning of the textbook, only basic things are known so far)*?

Comment: Please stop editing the question again and again. When we speak about events, which is the probability space we are working on. How is the whole story modelled?

Comment: @dan_fulea Well, OK, I guess it is modelled in the most logical way. The exact model is not given in the problem statement. So I guess we have to propose the most logical model (which makes sense) so that it gives us this answer $M/N$. But you are probably right, maybe that's part of the difficulty I am facing.

Comment: Then forget about being rigorous. You are writing a $P$ and do not define the $P$. Many textbooks do so, they are teaching "probability light", probability without probability spaces. In this case, the space is "cheap", it is usually a set, every subset is measurable, the probability is uniform. So the modelling part is easy. The only ingredient is the "set" we are working with. And exactly this set is the problem. For a parallel, consider the following problem. Which is the probability to get two pairs in one poker hand for the second player when cards are distributed cyclicly one by one?

Comment: You could suppose that the first $k-1$ people draw $C$ winning tickets and find  $P(B)= \sum_c P(C=c)P(B \mid C=c)$.  Here  $P(C=c)$ will be a hypergeometric probability and  $P(B \mid C=c)$ a conditional Bernoulli probability

Comment: In such a case modelling may forget about the other players, forget about the other cards, and say it is only the set of "good events" with two pairs among all subsets with five elements from all $52$ cards. The next person wants arrangements instead of subsets, order matters. The next person modelling will complain that cards are given in order, so i have after three turns say $9\spadesuit K\diamondsuit A\clubsuit$, and if all aces are already given in the round the probability is smaller to get two pairs now. So modelling here means also providing information to the first three cards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be solved by applying the rule: $$\text{probability=number of favorable outcomes divided by number of possible outcomes}$$This rule works if the outcomes are equiprobable (which is the case below).

It is IMV the best way to prove this problem rigorously.

---

For convenience number the tickets with $1,2,\dots,N$ and let the tickets with a number $\leq M$ be the winning tickets.

Fix one of the persons that draws a ticket.

For $i=1,2,\dots,N$ let $E_i$ denote the event that ticket $i$ is drawn by this person.

If $i$ and $j$ are distinct ticket numbers then there is no reason at all to think that the ticket with number $i$ has more (or less) chance than the ticket with number $j$ to become the ticket that is drawn by this person.

In short: $$P(E_i)\text{ does not depend on }i\tag1$$

Next to that is for sure that one of the tickets is drawn by the person so that:$$\sum_{i=1}^NP(E_i)=1\tag2$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we conclude for $i=1,\dots,N$ that: $$P(E_i)=\frac1N$$

Then consequently if $E$ denotes the event that the person draws a winning ticket:$$P(E)=P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^ME_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^MP(E_i)=\frac{M}N$$

---

**Edit** (concerning your efforts):

"Let's suppose it's person #$K$'s turn to draw and he draws some ticket $A$...."

Under that supposition $H_1$ and $B$ (as defined in your question) denote exactly the same event so that directly:$$P(B)=P(H_1)$$
The application of the total law of probability is not incorrect but is redundant (hence confusing).

"Obviously the probability of each ticket being a winning ticket is $M/N$..."

Indeed, and that tells us that: $$P(H_1)=\frac{M}N$$

So your end result is:$$P(B)=\frac{M}{N}$$ which agrees with the answer that I provided above.

IMV your approach is correct but is up to some level tarnished by the redundant use of the total probability law.

Comment: Just recall the question(s) posted by OP,  *I don't know if this approach is valid, is it?

If it's not, how can this problem be solved more rigorously?* So already having two questions is questionable on the site, but ok, let us take them one by one. His first question is about the validity of his Bayes rule application. (In case of an invalid argument, OP wants an alternative...) How does this answer address the question in foreground?

Comment: @dan_fulea This answer is incomplete because it does not address to that question. My considerations were to start with this and to have a better look at the question after publishing. Eventually followed by an edit to make it more complete.

Comment: @dan_fulea I have completed my answer. Further I cannot find any application of Bayes rule in the question.

Comment: Oh, OK, so my approach is valid. That is surprising to me. Thanks. I will read and reread your approach too. Seems to be very interesting.

Comment: @dan_fulea I am not sure we need to apply Bayes' rule or the total probability law. That was just my guess. If we can solve the problem just by using classical probability that's fine too.

Comment: The problem doesn't state the tickets are returned to the urn after drawing. Why is there "no reason at all to think" (1) be incorrect?

Comment: @Argyll Indeed they are not returned. But can you give me a reason why the ticket with e.g. number $5$ has more chance to become the ticket drawn by the person than the ticket with e.g. number $7$?

Comment: I know the answer and I have my reason to demonstrate why the 2 sets of events have equal probability. When it comes to proving, shouldn't we supply reasons of why something is as opposed to simply asking "if no one comes forward with a reason for something is not; then something is"?

Comment: @Argyll I could have stated in a bit more formal way that $P(E_i)=P(E_j)$ *by symmetry*. I just hope that this is enough for the OP.

Comment: I actually find the existing discussions more on the advanced side compared to what the problem seems to ask for. Arguing why person 1 winning has the same probability as person k winning, by considering the outcome of everyone's ticket, is precisely what the problem asks for. (Asking ppl to work out the arithmetic required in induction would be a bit evil. So I assume not.) And so it misses the core part of the problem is that's skipped

Comment: Also, why should it be "by symmetry" if the order of drawing is different? Drawing later means less tickets to draw from. It's no longer "symmetrical" to a previous person?

Comment: @Argyll This answer shows that the problem becomes far more easy (for instance compare with the answer of Will Orrik) if we do not focus on persons but instead focus on tickets. The symmetry rests on the fact that the tickets $i$ and $j$ are evidently in an equivalent position (which is not affected by the fact that the persons are ordered). This cannot be said of the ordered persons. A route is chosen that simply avoids this ordering, and this with success.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. We fix one person and then focus on the tickets. And by symmetry indeed $P(E_i)$ must be a constant, hence equal to $1/N$. I find it very nice. Thanks a lot, that's a nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

When you say you've proved it for players $1$ and $2$, I assume you did something like the following. For player $1$ it's immediate. For player $2$ the probability is
$$
\frac{M}{N}\frac{M-1}{N-1}+\frac{N-M}{N}\frac{M}{N-1}=\frac{M}{N(N-1)}(N-M+M-1)=\frac{M}{N}.
$$
You can do something similar for player $3$. The probability is
\begin{align}
&\frac{M}{N}\frac{M-1}{N-1}\frac{M-2}{N-2}+\frac{M}{N}\frac{N-M}{N-1}\frac{M-1}{N-2}+\frac{N-M}{N}\frac{M}{N-1}\frac{M-1}{N-2}+\frac{N-M}{N}\frac{N-M-1}{N-1}\frac{M}{N-2}\\
&\quad=\frac{M(M-1)}{N(N-1)(N-2)}(N-M+M-2)+\frac{(N-M)M}{N(N-1)(N-2)}(N-M-1+M-1)\\
&\quad=\frac{M(M-1)}{N(N-1)}+\frac{(N-M)M}{N(N-1)},
\end{align}
which you recognize as the probability for player $2$ (already shown to equal $M/N$).

This suggests that your idea of using induction will work. Define events
\begin{align}
&E_{j,l}\ :\ \text{exactly $j$ winning tickets drawn in first $\ell$ draws}\\
&F_\ell\ :\ \text{person $\ell$ draws a winning ticket}
\end{align}
The total probability law implies
$$
\Pr(F_{\ell+1})=\sum_{j=0}^\ell\Pr(F_{\ell+1}\mid E_{j,\ell})\Pr(E_{j,\ell})
=\sum_{j=0}^\ell\frac{M-j}{N-\ell}\Pr(E_{j,\ell}).
$$
The event $E_{j,\ell}$ can be written as the disjoint union
$$
E_{j,\ell} = (F_\ell\cap  E_{j-1,\ell-1})
\cup (F'_\ell \cap E_{j,\ell-1}),
$$
from which we get
\begin{align}
\Pr(E_{j,\ell})&=\Pr(F_\ell\mid E_{j-1,\ell-1})\Pr(E_{j-1,\ell-1})
+\Pr(F'_\ell\mid E_{j,\ell-1})\Pr(E_{j,\ell-1})\\
&=\frac{M-j+1}{N-\ell+1}\Pr(E_{j-1,\ell-1})+\frac{N-M-(\ell-1-j)}{N-\ell+1}\Pr(E_{j,\ell-1}).
\end{align}
Inserting this into the expression we got from the total probability law gives
\begin{align}
\Pr(F_{\ell+1})=&\sum_{j=1}^\ell\frac{M-j}{N-\ell}\frac{M-j+1}{N-\ell+1}\Pr(E_{j-1,\ell-1})+\sum_{j=0}^{\ell-1}\frac{M-j}{N-\ell}\frac{N-M-(\ell-1-j)}{N-\ell+1}\Pr(E_{j,\ell-1})\\
=&\sum_{j=0}^{\ell-1}\left(\frac{M-j-1}{N-\ell}\frac{M-j}{N-\ell+1}\Pr(E_{j,\ell-1}) + \frac{M-j}{N-\ell}\frac{N-M-\ell+1+j}{N-\ell+1}\Pr(E_{j,\ell-1})\right)\\
=&\sum_{j=0}^{\ell-1}\frac{M-j}{N-\ell+1}\Pr(E_{j,\ell-1})=\Pr(F_\ell).
\end{align}
In the first line we adjusted the limits of summation using $\Pr(E_{-1,\ell-1})=\Pr(E_{\ell,\ell-1})=0$. In the second line we shifted the summation index of the first sum by $1$.

Comment: As an alternative, there are $P(N,K)$ ways the draws may be done and there are $P(N-1,K-1)$ ways the draws may be done such that the $q^\text{th}$ card drawn, $1\le q\le K$, is card $i$, $1\le i\le N$. Note that the latter probability does not depend on either $q$  or $i$. The probability that the $q^\text{th}$ card drawn is a winning card is therefore $M\frac{P(N-1,K-1)}{P(N,K)}=M\frac{(N-1)(N-2)\ldots(N-K+1)}{N(N-1)(N-2)\ldots(N-K+1)}=\frac{M}{N}$.

Comment: The author who posed the problem seems to want you to address the issue of order in which the players draw, and to show that the probability that a player wins does not depend on the player's order in the draw. Both of my proposed proofs draw specific attention to order. I personally feel that your proposed proof is fine, although overly complicated for the reasons drhab discusses, but I suspect it wouldn't satisfy a person who was not already convinced about the irrelevance of order. I would hope that one or both of my arguments would persuade such a person.

Comment: Thanks. It will take me some time to understand this solution. What is $F'_\ell$, is it the complement of $F_\ell$?

Comment: Yes, $F'_\ell$ is the complement of $F_\ell$. The origin of that line is the observation that if there are exactly $j$ winning tickets in the first $\ell$ draws, then either player $\ell$ draws a winning ticket and $j-1$ of the preceding players draw winning tickets, or else player $\ell$ draws a losing ticket and $j$ of the preceding players draw winning tickets.

Comment: I went through your proof. This is really cute. I didn't imagine it would be possible to do this whole calculation without finding some explicit formulas for the probabilities $Pr(E_{j,l})$ But you show here that this is exactly what happens. Turns out we don't need the explicit formulas for $Pr(E_{j,l})$ to do this derivation. Very nice! Also this proof is more convincing, I think, that the one by drhab. Thank you.

Comment: Nice. It is always good to have two ways that confirm eachother.

Answer (score 2):

In such cases, there are two parts of the computation, when being rigurous is an issue. The first part concerns modelling the situation, finding a mathematical framework that best suits the presented situation. (One has to model the case by using only the *a priori* information. This is already a point where people may start to question the process of making a bet story a probability space with a certain probability and an event to be evaluated.) The second part happens only inside mathematics, here we have less problems.

So i suppose that the mentioned textbook has already at the beginning an idea what is a "simplest" probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal P(\Omega),\Bbb P)$, with a finite set $\Omega$, each of its subsets is measurable, the probability $\Bbb P$ being the uniform one. (I hate textbook where probability is done without any probability space, but rules are immediately proven, and conditional probabilities are defined by a formula, which can be written so only in discrete cases. If this is the case, there is no rigorous approach.)

Let us model the situation.
One "faithful" way to model so that the "story" is parallely mirrored is the following one. We can *a priori* label the tickets by using numbers from $1$ to $N$ so that the tickets with number $\le M$ are winning. Peoples $P_1,P_2,\dots,P_n$ come now to the urn and extract a ticket in their order. This leads to a result, which is a permutation of the set (with elements) $1,2,\dots,N$. Model the situation using
$$
\Omega=S_N\ ,
$$
the set of permutations of the $N$ tickets. Uniform probability on it.
For some permutation $\sigma$, our person, the person labelled $K$ extracts ticket $\sigma(K)$.
The wanted event is
$$
A(K) = \{\ \sigma\in S_N\ :\ \sigma(K)\le M\ \}
\ .
$$
Now we have a simple combinatorial problem to compute the numbers of elements of $A$. Since the *group* of permutations $S_N$ actions on $\Omega$ (which is obtained by applying the forgetful functor from groups to sets on $S_N$) in a way compatible with the probability, use this action to see that $A(K)$ and $A(1)$ have the same probability. Now enumerate elements $\sigma$ of $S_N$ as usual. Pick one ticket for the first entry in $\sigma$. From the remained pick one ticket for the second entry in $\sigma$... This is a kind of a tree structure used to enumerate $S_N$. Obviously, the first step is enough to decide if the element $\sigma$ is in $A(1)$ or not. There are $M$ good possibilities among the $N$ possible ramifications at the first step, so the probability is $M/N$.

Alternatively, enumerate $S_N$ by building the tree and taking for the first ramification the value of a "random $\sigma$" in its $K$.th position.

---

Having the space, it is of course possible to apply Bayes rule as written in the question, and the argument is also valid. (But the counting argument is the direct approach. Since the ingredients in Bayes rule must be also computed by counting.)

---

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will read it and think it over.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know why the probability for first person to draw winning is $M/N$, it remains to show that the probability of winning for any subsequent person is the same as the first one.

To do that, you can consider each individual event as the total outcome of everyone's ticket; and see that the set of events for 1st person winning have the same number of elements as the set of events for any other person winning.

---

It is ok to order the set of tickets with $T_1,T_2,T_3,...,T_N$ where $T_i$ is a winning ticket iff $i<=M$. And we will consider the tickets as shuffled in the urn. We will actually only talk about the labels (indices) for these tickets. So we may as well think that the tickets are numerals $1,2,3,...,N$ where winning tickets are less than $M$.

Let's label the persons in the order they draw as well: $P_1,P_2,...,P_K$.

An outcome of everyone's ticket is $\{f(P_i)\}_i$ for $i=1,2,...,K$ where $f$ is a permutation on the set of tickets $\{T_i\}_i$.

Then consider the set of outcomes corresponding to person $P_1$ winning, ie. $f(P_1)<=M$ and the same for person $P_k$ winning, ie. $f(P_k)<=M$. Call them set $1$ vs set $k$.

For every such outcome in set $1$, simply swap the ticket between person $1$ and person $k$, you will have an outcome belonging to set $k$.

This swapping has a natural inverse: swapping the tickets back.

So no 2 distinct outcomes in set $1$ can be mapped to the same outcome in set $k$ under swapping. (For any claim that a different outcome in set $1$ gets swapped to the same outcome in set $k$, you swap back and you get an identical outcome in set $1$.)

The image of swapping over set $1$ fully covers set $k$ because, if any outcome in set $k$ was hypothetically missing, you identify an outcome in set $1$ by swapping back from the hypothetical missing outcome in set $k$; swap forward again; the hypothetical missing outcome is in the image of the swap after all.

Since we identified a bijective function between set $1$ and set $k$, ie. swapping the tickets between person $1$ and person $k$, the two sets have equal number of elements.

Thus, you can argue that the two events have equal probability.

Depending on the context, you may satisfy the problem's author by saying: swapping between permutations is bijective and skip some of the concept argument.

---

As for your current approach, @Henry's comment and @Will Orrick's answer with induction show that it can work. But I suspect that the problem's author has a simpler solution than induction in mind.